# Ajax search functionality in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have tried adding ajax search functionality to my site using the admin-ajax.php file and also without it, but with no luck. I am using JQuery in other parts of the website too and the scripts stop working when due to this code. When I comment it out, the other scripts (like sliding navbar) start working again. This is the code -
---- functions.php ------

```
function wpa56343_search()
 {
  global $wp_query;
  $search = $_POST['search_val'];
  $args = array(
    's' => $search,
    'posts_per_page' => 5
  );
  $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  get_template_part( 'search-results' );

  exit;
 }
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpa56343_search', 'wpa56343_search'); 
 add_action('wp_ajax_wpa56343_search', 'wpa56343_search');
```

---- JS file ----

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
$("#searchsubmit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var search_val=$("#s").val(); 
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action:'wpa56343_search', 
            search_string:search_val
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#results').append(response);
        }
});   
});
```

and I have used wp_enqueue_script in the functions file for enqueuing scripts. When I add this code, all jquery functionality just stops and for the search page, I get redirected to the default page. The submit buttons click event is also not getting triggered. Can someone please advice? i am trying out everything but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: most wordpress templates use jQuery.noConflict() so `$` is likely undefined. Are errors thrown in console? Try changing ready handler to `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`

Comment: I am fairly new to this. Where do I debug this? or see errors? I dont see errors in my browser window. The handler is already jquery(document)ready.... which one do you mean ?

Comment: hit F12 and look in console...just add the `$` argument to your `ready` the way I've shown and see if that helps

Comment: @charlietfl - Oh Thank you! This console thing is awesome! My problem is not solved yet, but at least life is easier now. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I logged in to THANK YOU for your question, it solved my tinkering big time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this problem. yay! I was unsuccessful in getting the above code to work, but I found my solution on this blog by David Albert (Thank you David!)

http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-use-ajax-with-php-on-your-wp-site-without-a-plugin/

Its a well written article and easy to understand. Under the comments section in my name, you can find code which is specific to search. (Retrieving and rendering results). 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **get_template_part**. Pass data in json format and use that data.

```
function wpa56343_search()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $search = $_POST['search_val'];
    $args = array(
        's' => $search,
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    );
    $results = new WP_Query( $args );
    echo json_encode( $results );
    exit;
}
```

Also changed js code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#search-container").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var search_val=$("#s").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
                action:'wpa56343_search',
                search_string:search_val
            },
            success:function(data){ alert(data);
                $('#results').append(data);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bhumi for your response. Heres whats happening-
1. $("#search-container").click ... gets called. The $("#searchbutton").click ... does not work for some reason.

2. var search_val=$("#s").val() always returns null no matter what I enter in the search box.

3. $('#results').append(response); gives the following error in console Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: You have to chanage #id with your desire id and change response with data and after parsing it.

Comment: made some changes. But now, when I hit submit the preventDefault functionality doesnt work. The default search behavior occurs and the search.php file is loaded. I am not sure why this is happening if I have clearly written e.preventDefault(); Any ideas?

Comment: Have you replace #search-container with your desire id? and try to alert into onclick and check once

Comment: Yes I did that Bhumi. The alert never gets called.